# Visual Basic - Wait for webpage to load not working

Tags: vb.net, browser, sleep

I'm trying to load a website, wait for it to fully load and then display a message box when it's loaded.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
    Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = 4
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop
    MsgBox("Loaded")
End Sub
```

However, when I use this nothing happens, at all despite waiting about 30 seconds. If I remove everything to leave me with...

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
End Sub
```

..., It loads fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI isn't going to load the page because you've tied up the UI thread in an infinite (or at least near infinite) loop.

Instead of *waiting* for the browser to load, asynchronously respond to the [*event* of the browser loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_events.aspx).  Something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    MsgBox("Loaded")
End Sub
```

Any time you find yourself wanting to "pause" an application to wait for something to happen, it's highly likely that you need to subscribe to an *event* when that something happens.

Comment: Thanks this has solved my original problem but now I've noticed some pages trigger the message box to appear multiple times. For about 5 times I click 'close' on the message box, a part of the webpages loads a bit more and then another message box opens.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm seeing this right, its due to the fact you're making the main thread stop everytime you're running the check. Couldn't you just add an event handler on the [DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event?